# How to call the console debug panel in a Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, hotkeys, add-on

What's the Javascript function that calls the console debug panel (`CTRL+SHIFT+J`) on Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to open the console pannel

```
var win = event.target.ownerDocument.defaultView;
win.gDevToolsBrowser.selectToolCommand(win.gBrowser, "webconsole");
```

Also possible with

```
HUDConsoleUI.toggleBrowserConsole();
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need this code

```
event.target.ownerDocument.gDevToolsBrowser.selectToolCommand(win.gBrowser, "webconsole");
```

Nothing else is needed ;)